# Validation on RadioButton of same group in .net using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I want to give validation on two radiobuttons of same group using javascript in .net. There will be a button clicking on which the text of selected radiobutton will store on database. But if none of the radio button is selected then a alert will be shown and nothing will be stored in database. Please give me a solution

Comment: What you've tried to do? Provide [mcve] with UI/page markup and/or code behind to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Is it a radio button list?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its a radio button list, on client click of button,

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Validate" OnClientClick="return Validate()" />
```

embed the below function.

```
function Validate() {
    var rb = document.getElementById("<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID%>");
    var radio = rb.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var isChecked = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
        if (radio[i].checked) {
            isChecked = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isChecked) {
        alert("Please select an option!");
    } 
    return isChecked;
}
```